# How to upgrade to HWE 12.04.5?

Tags: oem

My system: Brand new Dell OptiPlex XE2 with 12.04 pre-installed by Dell.

I applied all security updates via update manager. Now Update Manager tells me this:

[image: Dear Ubuntu user, your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support on 2015-04-30. After this date, security updates for critical parts of your system will no longer be available. We recommend you upgrade your system. If you experience any issue after this upgrade, please post a message on askubuntu.com using the tag 'oem' (you can use this link: http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/ask?tags=oem).For more information, please see:]

I click the Upgrade button and I get this error:

[image: Package does not exist. Check the spelling of the package name, and that the appropriate repository is enabled. Details: Package xserver-xorg-lts-trusty isn't available]

How do I fix this and upgrade my system to the latest 12.04.5?

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 _Precise_ - Build amd64 LIVE Binary 20130203-13:50]/ precise main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-dell.list**

`deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ precise-dell public
deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ precise-dell public`

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-oem-sp1.list**

`deb http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ precise-oem-sp1 public
deb-src http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ precise-oem-sp1 public`

Comment: You're not going to be updating to 12.04 if you do that; you're going to upgrade to 14.04. With that out of the way, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update` before you try again.

Comment: I do not need to upgrade to 14.04 LTS. Read the link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL_OEM

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that. It says it wants to upgrade to Trusty, which is 14.04. I believe a simple `sudo apt-get upgrade` will work

Comment: apt-get update followed by apt-get upgrade and also apt-get dist-upgrade do nothing, i.e., 0 packages upgraded/installed/removed. Basically, the instructions provided by  wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL_OEM and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL_OEM?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=standard+upgrade+process don't work in my situation. I have a support ticket open with Dell as well and waiting for their response.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of /etc/apt/source.lists? We'd like to make make sure that precise-updates is correctly listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the security updates enabled, but not the regular updates.

Make sure to activate precise-updates in your software sources as explained at in [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Updates_Tab).

Then, follow again the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL_OEM

Comment: Ah! That might be it! Won't be able to try this until Mon or Tue next week. Will post back my results.

Comment: Working now. Had to enable Recommended updates as suggested, and also click button to Check for updates. Then clicked the upgrade button in the dialog box of my original post. Now uname -r reports 3.13.0-77-generic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Since this is a fresh installation, you should at least update and upgrade the local packages, if you haven't done it already:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
2. To install the HWE stack of Ubuntu Precise:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty
   ```

   ([Source](//wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Server-1))