# How to get 12.04.3 to a supported LTS kernel (3.13.xx kernel or 3.2.xxx kernel)?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I installed a friends PC with a 12.04.3 install medium. I thought with 12.04 I had always long term support. But looking at kernel support (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.A12.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support ) it seems I have a problem.

## QUESTION

Now my problem is that I am stuck with 12.04.3's kernel being

```
linux-image-3.5.0-54-generic_3.5.0-54.81~precise1_amd64.deb 16-Jul-2014 18:15   39M
```

which is from 2014 (not so great)

How can I get a updated kernel (i.e. a 3.2.xxx as in 12.04.1, or a 3.13.xxx in 12.04.5)?

I tried `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` but that did not help get a supported kernel. Am I lost with a unsupported kernel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade to HWE 12.04.5?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/731868/how-to-upgrade-to-hwe-12-04-5)

Answer (score 0):

You can install kernel 3.13 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

Next time it is better to download and install the latest point release, like 12.04.5. You will not need to install lot's of updates and will have the latest major kernel for this LTS release.